# How to access protected database in Actions on Google using Google Sign in?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, actions-on-google, google-signin

I have a firestore database and I want to access it in actions on google app.The problem is I have implemented account linking but I don't know how to use it's user id to authenticate users to access the firestore.I have set the rules to only give reading access to authenticated google users.I am entirely new to this platform can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even with your database rules being marked as secure from a client perspective, you can use the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) to access and manipulate all of the data in your database.